# Transferring Vector Resultset to another database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

If someone could assist with this it would be great.
I have two identical MS Access databases, only the filenames are different.
Fist db is on my local computer, the second db is on a mapped network drive.
I can do a search on the second db, return a resultset in a vector and can display the results in a JTable. 
Question - Does anyone know if it is possible to then transfer this resultset to the database on the local computer??

I can transfer a single record no problem, but an entire resultset I'm not sure.
I'm using Java/JDBC.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by transfer: saving the data in the Vector in your local database or what?

Comment: Yes that would be correct. The Vector contains data from DB1, I want to place it in DB2.

Comment: Ok, then your problem is about how to save it? Because it seems pretty simple: navigate through each entry in the vector, then save each one.

Comment: Thanks Luiggi, sounds about right. I was thinking I could just 'dump' the resultSet into the DB2.

Comment: Nathan, I don't want to use CSV files. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty simple. Open connection to DB1, iterate over the vector (or RS), insert in DB2 each entry. Close the connection.

Since you didn't post any code no way to know what you exactly need.

Hope this helps you.